# what is the event name for swipe left in windows 8 html5 javascript app?

Tags: javascript, html, touch, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I want to capture the event when user swipes from left to right or right to left on a image .And also vertical swpie events such as top to bottom swipe and bottom to up swipe .Are there any event names for this .

I am using the following statement for just touch/tap event.Is there  any similar event for swipe left or swipe right ?

```
 WinJS.utilities.id("imgHomePage").listen("MSPointerUp",funcTapHandler,false);
```

Answer (score 1):

The pan events on an object can be detected using the `MSGestureStart` (or `MSGestureEnd`) events.

When you tap and hold a `MsGestureHold` will be fired and then `MSGestureStart` and others when you start dragging Take a look to [this page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh968249%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for an example you can use to inspect these messages (below a quick extract):

> When the user touches the surface and keeps their finger there, it fires an **onmsgesturehold** event. When the user swipes their finger, **onmsgesturestart**, **onmsgesturechange**, and **onmsgestureend** events are fired. If the user swipes quickly, an **onmsinertiastart** event is fired. The **onmsinertiastart** event is followed by a series of **onmsgesturechange** events, depending on the speed of the swipe, before an **onmsgestureend** event is fired. The **onmsinertiastart** event can help your code differentiate between a slow move and a quick flick, and react accordingly, like continuing movement of an object even though the contact with the surface is broken.

Comment: This isn't going to give you all that you need. If you wish to have a consisten set of gestures, I would recommend using the GestureRecogniser class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.gesturerecognizer). The sample for this should help a lot: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Manipulations-and-gestures-26918bb3